# Getting wifi passwords with a mac

Tags: bash, macos

I'm trying to use the bash shell to get a wifi profile for a certain network, and from that, the password

What I'm looking for is basically a mac equivalent to `netsh wlan show profile name="name" key=clear`, which gets exactly what I want with windows

I have looked into the airport and networksetup commands on mac, but still have yet to find something that will either show me the network profiles or, even better, what's inside.

Does anyone have any ideas or at least something to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's okay to use a Node.js script for this, you might have a look at [wifi-password-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wifi-password-cli) which does exactly what you want:

```
$ wifi-password --help

  Usage
    $ wifi-password [network-name]

  Example
    $ wifi-password
    unicorns
    $ wifi-password foo-network
    foosecretpassword
```

(Sample taken from the tool's documenation)

To use it, simply run (supposed that Node.js has already been installed on your system before):

```
$ npm install -g wifi-password-cli
```

Comment: I'm open to using a script, but is there a way to do it that doesn't require a third-party software?

Comment: You might have a look at how this Node.js script does it ;-)

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the Admin Username and Password?

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is:

```
security find-generic-password -ga "ROUTERNAME" | grep "password:"
```

Add the WIFI name you are connected in the place of ROUTERNAME

Answer (score 0):

Simply run the command from terminal app

```bash
security find-generic-password -wa <WIFI_NAME>
```

Replace `<WIFI_NAME>` with your Wifi Name.
A prompt will ask you for username and password.